# REST API issue with chained call

Tags: api, rest

Having a horrible time trying to get api.Contact.get into the URL.  The api explorer always puts into a &json{} array.  api.Contact.get is an empty array and that defeats most other ways of getting it into the REST call.  No example provided by Civicrm uses an empty array in code demonstration.  The simplexml example accepts and passes on the json, but I don't get anything back.  I've also tried a CURL call that I wrote and I tried mimicing the cURL call used by the civicrm_api3 class (which also does not work with the json array).

I'd like to know if anyone can tell me how to get a functional equivalent of

**/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Membership&action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"return":"contact_id,join_date","status_id":["New","Current"],"options":{"limit":10},"api.Contact.get":{}}**

I have a case where going after the linked contacts would be miserably slow and inefficient.

Is there working php code ANYWHERE that can use the json array in the examples?  If so, can you tell me where to find it?